# Errors encountered when trying to create Apps for Office in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, apps-for-office

I was trying to create a Apps for Office project on Visual Studio 2013. However, I end up getting these errors:

> Unhandled exception occurred while creating a SharePoint project item from the following location: `c:\users\benjamin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BindingZonesSandbox\BindingZonesSandbox\BindingZonesSandboxManifest.`
>   `Exception: InvalidOperationException.` Message: "An error occurred
>   while trying to load a required component. Please ensure that the
>   following prerequisite component is installed:
>
> Microsoft Exchange WebServices."Unhandled exception occurred while calling method 'OnCollectionChanged' of type
>   `'System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager,
>   WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`. `Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException.` Message: "An error occurred while
>   trying to load a required component. Please ensure that the following
>   prerequisite component is installed:
>
> Microsoft Exchange WebServices."Error: this template attempted to load component assembly `'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`. For more information on this problem
>   and how to enable this template, please see documentation on
>   Customizing Project Templates.

It seems to be asking me to install some prerequisites but I don't know what exactly they are asking me to install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering if you are able to publish to an existing website. I'm finding this error at the same time I'm finding myself unable to publish to an existing website - all after installing update4

Comment: I am having the same problem... Have you found the solution? If so, please could you add it for the community?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to tell use which type of project you have created?

Please make sure that you are creating "App for Office" instead of "App for SharePoint".